# Calculate a tricky sum in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sum

With the following variables:

```
m = 1:4; n = 1:32;
phi = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100);
theta = linspace(-pi, pi, 50);

S_mn = <a 4x32 coefficient matrix, corresponding to m and n>;
```

how do I compute the sum over *m* and *n* of `S_mn*exp(1i*(m*theta + n*phi))`, i.e.

[image: $\sum_m \sum_n S_mn exp(i(m\theta+n\phi))]

I've thought of things like

```
[m, n] = meshgrid(m,n);
[theta, phi] = meshgrid(theta,phi);
r_mn = S_mn.*exp(1i*(m.*theta + n.*phi));
thesum = sum(r_mn(:));
```

but that requires `theta` and `phi` to have the same number of elements as `m` and `n`, and it gives me just one element in return - I want a matrix the the size of `meshgrid(theta,phi)`, regardless of the sizes of `theta` and `phi` (i.e. I want to be able to evaluate the sum as a function of `theta` and `phi`).

How do I do this calculation in matlab?

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know what S is...

```
S = randn(4,32);

[m,n] = ndgrid(1:4,1:32);
fun = @(theta,phi) sum(sum(S.*exp(sqrt(-1)*(m*theta + n*phi))));
```

Works fine for me.

```
fun(pi,3*pi/2)
ans =
          -15.8643373238676 -      1.45785698818839i
```

If you now wish to do this for a large set of values phi and theta, a pair of loops now are the trivial solution. Or, you can do it all in one computation, although the arrays will get larger. Still not hard. WTP?

You do realize that both meshgrid and ndgrid take more than just two arguments? So it is time to learn how to use bsxfun, and then squeeze.

```
[m,n,theta,phi] = ndgrid(1:4,1:32,linspace(-pi, pi, 50),linspace(0, 2*pi, 100));
res = bsxfun(@times,S,exp(sqrt(-1)*(m.*theta + n.*phi)));
res = squeeze(sum(sum(res,1),2));
```

Or do this, which will be a bit faster. The previous computation took my machine .07 seconds. This last one took .05, so some savings by using bsxfun heavily.

```
m = (1:4)';
n = 1:32;
[theta,phi] = ndgrid(linspace(-pi, pi, 50),linspace(0, 2*pi, 100));
theta = reshape(theta,[1,1,size(theta)]);
phi = reshape(phi,size(theta));
res = bsxfun(@plus,bsxfun(@times,m,theta*sqrt(-1)),bsxfun(@times,n,phi*sqrt(-1)));
res = bsxfun(@times,S,exp(res));
res = squeeze(sum(sum(res,1),2));
```

If you need to do the above 2000 times, so it should take 100 seconds to do. WTP? Get some coffee and relax.

Comment: I'm going to do this for high high resolutions in `phi` and `theta` over the entire range [-pi, pi] x [0, 2pi], for 2000 timesteps. I need better performance than this.

Comment: Perhaps if you had said something about your needs in the first place, it might help in the future?

Comment: Anyway, just WANTING a computer to run faster does not help. There are a fixed number of multiples and adds here, and your computer will only process them as fast as it will do. If you need a faster computer, then buy one. As it is, the above computaqtion is fully vectorized, with no slop in it.

Answer (score 0):

First save the size of each variable:

```
size_m = size(m);
size_n = size(n);
size_theta = size(theta);
size_phi = size(phi);
```

Use [ngrid](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ndgrid.html) function like this:

```
[theta, phi, m, n] = ngrid(theta, phi, m, n)
```

This will give you an array with 4 dimensions (one for each of your variables: theta, phi, m, n). Now you can calculate this:

```
m.*theta + n.*phi
```

Now you need to make S_mn have 4 dimensions with sizes size_theta, size_phi, size_m, size_n like this:

```
S_tpmn = repmat(S_mn, [size_theta size_phi size_m size_n]);
```

Now you can calculate your sum like this:

```
aux_sum = S_tpmn.*exp(1i*(m.*theta + n.*phi));
```

Finally you can sum along the last 2 dimensions (m and n) to get an array with 2 dimensions with size size_theta by size_phi:

```
final_sum = sum(sum(aux_sum, 4), 3);
```

Note: I don't have access to Matlab right now, so I can't test if this actually works.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could go about this.

One way is to create a function(-handle) that returns the sum as a function of theta and phi, and then use `arrayfun` to do the sums. Another is to fully vectorize the computation, though that will use more memory.

The `arrayfun` version:

```
[m, n] = meshgrid(m,n);

sumHandle = @(theta,phi)sum(reshape(...
    S_mn.*exp(1i(m*theta + n*phi)),...
    [],1)) 

[theta, phi] = meshgrid(theta,phi);

sumAsFunOfThetaPhi = arrayfun(sumHandle,theta,phi);
```

The vectorized version:

```
[m, n] = meshgrid(m,n);
m = permute(m(:),[2 4 1 3]); %# vector along dim 3
n = permute(n(:),[2 3 4 1]); %# vector along dim 4

S_mn = repmat( permute(S_mn,[3 4 1 2]), length(theta),length(phi));

theta = theta(:); %# vector along dim 1 (phi is along dim 2 b/c of linspace)

fullSum = S_mn.* exp( 1i*(...
    bsxfun(@plus,...
       bsxfun(@times, m, theta),...
       bsxfun(@times, n, phi),...
    )));

sumAsFunOfThetaPhi = sum(sum( fullSum, 3),4);
```