# Double Summation in MATLAB and vectorized loops

Tags: matlab, optimization, for-loop, sum, vectorization

Here's my attempt in implementing this lovely formula.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7348856/Picture1.png

```
%WIGNER Computes Wigner-Distribution on an image (difference of two images).
function[wd] = wigner(difference)
%Image size
[M, N, ~] = size(difference);
%Window size (5 x 5)
Md = 5;
Nd = 5;
%Fourier Transform
F = fft2(difference);
%Initializing the wigner picture
wd = zeros(M, N, 'uint8');
lambda =0.02;
value = (4/(Md*Nd));
for x = 1+floor(Md/2):M - floor(Md/2)
    for y = 1+floor(Nd/2):N - floor(Nd/2)
        for l = -floor(Nd/2) : floor(Nd/2)
            for k = -floor(Md/2) : floor(Md/2)
                kernel = exp(-lambda * norm(k,l));
                kernel = kernel * value;
                theta = 4 * pi * ((real(F(x, y)) * (k/M) )+ (imag(F(x, y)) * (l/N)));
                wd(x, y) = (wd(x, y)) + (cos(theta) * difference(x + k, y + l) * difference(x - k, y - l) * (kernel));
            end
        end
    end
end
end
```

As you can see, the outer two loops are for the sliding window, while the remaining inner ones are for the variables of the summation.

Now, my request for you my beloved stackoverflow users is: Can you help me improve these very nasty for loops that take more than its share of time, and turn it into vectorized loops?
And will that improvement be of a significant change?

Thank you.

Comment: I suppose you'll see an improvement for large values of `M` and `N`. How big are they?

Comment: I can tell you vectorization will definitely improve computation speed. When MATLAB does vector math, it goes down all the way to your PC's [BLAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) for optimization.

Comment: @EitanT The image dimensions are 320(N) x 240(M).

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666640/calculate-a-tricky-sum-in-matlab).

Comment: @EitanT I looked at the link you posted. So far I converted all of the loops to meshgrids; but I've encountered a problem with the norm function. I want it to use the elements of the matrix instead of the matrix whole i.e. norm(K, L); where [L,K] = meshgrid(-floor(Nd/2):floor(Nd/2), -floor(Md/2):floor(Md/2));

Comment: So what is the problem you encounter with the norm?

Comment: @EitanT I want to use the norm(x, y) where it returns the norm of two numbers, rather than the norm of a Matrix, but it keeps using the latter.

Comment: Can you post the command syntax? I might be tell you where it went wrong.

Comment: 'Kern =  exp(-lambda * norm(K,L));'

Comment: There's your problem, you're using the name `norm`, don't do that. It is reserved for the function with the same name, and that's why MATLAB keeps using the original definition. Use another name, like `new_norm` or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those four nested loops are basically processing each pixel in the image in a sliding-neighborhood style. I immediately thought of [NLFILTER](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/nlfilter.html) and [IM2COL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/im2col.html) functions.

Here is my attempt at vectorizing the code. Note that I haven't thoroughly tested it, or compared performance against loop-based solution:

```
function WD = wigner(D, Md, Nd, lambda)
    %# window size and lambda
    if nargin<2, Md = 5; end
    if nargin<3, Nd = 5; end
    if nargin<4, lambda = 5; end

    %# image size
    [M,N,~] = size(D);

    %# kernel = exp(-lambda*norm([k,l])
    [K,L] = meshgrid(-floor(Md/2):floor(Md/2), -floor(Nd/2):floor(Nd/2));
    K = K(:); L = L(:);
    kernel = exp(-lambda .* sqrt(K.^2+L.^2));

    %# frequency-domain part
    F = fft2(D);

    %# f(x+k,y+l) * f(x-k,y-l) * kernel
    C = im2col(D, [Md Nd], 'sliding');
    X1 = bsxfun(@times, C .* flipud(C), kernel);

    %# cos(theta)
    C = im2col(F, [Md Nd], 'sliding');
    C = C(round(Md*Nd/2),:);    %# take center pixels
    theta = bsxfun(@times, real(C), K/M) + bsxfun(@times, imag(C), L/N);
    X2 = cos(4*pi*theta);

    %# combine both parts for each sliding-neighborhood
    WD = col2im(sum(X1.*X2,1), [Md Nd], size(F), 'sliding') .* (4/(M*N));

    %# pad array with zeros to be of same size as input image
    WD = padarray(WD, ([Md Nd]-1)./2, 0, 'both');
end
```

For what its worth, here is the loop-based version with the improvement that [@Laurbert515](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10759055/97160) suggested:

```
function WD = wigner_loop(D, Md, Nd, lambda)
    %# window size and lambda
    if nargin<2, Md = 5; end
    if nargin<3, Nd = 5; end
    if nargin<4, lambda = 5; end

    %# image size
    [M,N,~] = size(D);

    %# frequency-domain part
    F = fft2(D);

    WD = zeros([M,N]);
    for l = -floor(Nd/2):floor(Nd/2)
        for k = -floor(Md/2):floor(Md/2)
            %# kernel = exp(-lambda*norm([k,l])
            kernel = exp(-lambda * norm([k,l]));

            for x = (1+floor(Md/2)):(M-floor(Md/2))
                for y = (1+floor(Nd/2)):(N-floor(Nd/2))
                    %# cos(theta)
                    theta = 4 * pi * ( real(F(x,y))*k/M + imag(F(x,y))*l/N );

                    %# f(x+k,y+l) * f(x-k,y-l)* kernel
                    WD(x,y) = WD(x,y) + ( cos(theta) * D(x+k,y+l) * D(x-k,y-l) * kernel );
                end
            end
        end
    end
    WD = WD * ( 4/(M*N) );
end
```

and how I test it (based on what I understood from the [paper](http://www.di.ubi.pt/~lfbaa/biorecPubs/otcbvs2010.pdf) you [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676582/double-summation-implementing-wigners-distribution-on-thermal-images) linked to):

```
%# difference between two consecutive frames
A = imread('AT3_1m4_02.tif');
B = imread('AT3_1m4_03.tif');
D = imsubtract(A,B);
%#D = rgb2gray(D);
D = im2double(D);

%# apply Wigner-Distribution
tic, WD1 = wigner(D); toc
tic, WD2 = wigner_loop(D); toc
figure(1), imshow(WD1,[])
figure(2), imshow(WD2,[])
```

you might then need to scale/normalize the matrix, and apply thresholding...

Comment: Hey Amro. First of all, thanks for the hard work. Second, I get this error when I run the function:-
??? Error using ==> reshape
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.

Error in ==> col2im at 84
    a = reshape(b,mat(1)-block(1)+1,mat(2)-block(2)+1);

Error in ==> wignerVector at 29
    WD = col2im(sum(X1.*X2,1), [Md Nd], size(F), 'sliding') .* (4/(M*N));"

Comment: @Absi: are you sure you are working with grayscale images? if not call RGB2GRAY prior to this..

Comment: Yep, I'm positive. Here's a sample https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7348856/img_00003.bmp I send the difference of this image and the one after it to wigner.

Comment: @Absi: actually it is an RGB image even though all channels are equal (`ndims(img)==3`). You *need* to call RGB2GRAY...

Comment: Ah that's correct. Now it appears to be working. Thanks a million bro. I've got a question for you though; when using the outside value that is multiplied by the double summation (i.e. 4/(M*N)) the image turns pitch black. I've changed that to 4/(Md*Nd) and it displays a good result. Do you have any modest idea why?

Comment: @Absi: I was just following the equation given in the [paper](http://www.di.ubi.pt/~lfbaa/biorecPubs/otcbvs2010.pdf).. Either way it shouldn't matter; as I mentioned in the last part of my answer, the result needs to be scaled to the proper range of [0,1] (one way to do that when viewing the image is to call IMSHOW with an empty array as second argument: `imshow(img,[])`)

Answer (score 4):

this might not be what you are asking, but it seems (at first glance) that the order of the summations are independent and that instead of {x,y,l,k} you could go {l,k,x,y}. doing this will allow you to evaluate kernel fewer times by keeping it in the outer most loop.

Comment: This is a splendid suggestion; the function improved to an extraordinary degree. I salute you.

Comment: +1 for Laurbert515. @Absi, if you decide that this answer is helpful (even if you don't see it as the complete answer to your question), you should at least upvote it by pressing the up arrow (▲).

Comment: @EitanT I did try to upvote; unfortunately I need to have a reputation of 15. My apologies to Laurbert515.

Comment: @Absi Oh okay, I didn't pay attention to your the amount of you reputation. My apologies to you, sir :)

Comment: @EitanT It's ok man, thank you for taking the time to help me :)